# add interval to timestamp on record creation trigger

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to do what on the surface seems a simple task. I have a table with the fields `expires_at` (timestamp) `ttl` (integer) and `name` (text)

the `ttl` is supplied as 86400. I want to set the `expires_at` field to be the current timestamp + the ttl.

this is my trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.set_expires() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $_$
    BEGIN
      NEW.expires_at := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + (NEW.ttl || ' seconds')::INTERVAL;
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
  $_$;
```

however, when this runs, I get the current time in the `expires_at` field.

if I change the trigger to be

```
NEW.expires_at := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + (86400 || ' seconds')::INTERVAL;
```

then the `expires_at` is set correctly.

This would imply that `NEW.ttl` is not set, but if I add

```
NEW.name:=NEW.ttl;
```

to the trigger, `name` is set to 86400. So I am somewhat confused about what I am doing wrong here and would appreciate some help ;)

Comment: Is this triggered for `BEFORE` or `AFTER`? And which version are you on?

Comment: Your function seems to work for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7a758dffdf9337345d28d8e13d909a11

Comment: Is it possible this is what is happening?: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=115129ea293643b64cf3d7ab78ae8c9e Modified @NickBarnes fiddle to include `DEFAULT current_timestamp` on the `expires_at` column and changed from `BEFORE` to `AFTER` for the trigger.

Comment: well, crap .. I deleted my trigger, copied in from the dbfiddle .. and it's now working. I  have no idea what is different - a diff on the two different triggers generates this

 diff tmp/p1.sql tmp/p2.sql
1c1
< CREATE FUNCTION public.set_expires() RETURNS trigger
---
> CREATE FUNCTION set_expires() RETURNS trigger
9d8
<
\ No newline at end of file

so I am at a loss - but it's working !

Answer (score 0):

Althought your version should work (as @NickBarnes shows in the fiddle), maybe you could try to change the syntax to

```
NEW.expires_at := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + NEW.ttl * interval '1 second';
```